# Static Cells option is not available in UITableViewController Xib out side the storyBoard

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

Whe trying to use static cells in the UITableViewController from XIB outside the stroyboard, I could not find the option for choosing the static cell and dynamic cell option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static table cells are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances.

It is available on the StoryBoard UITableViewController instances

Create UITableViewController in StoryBoard